# Как вставлять php скрипты в html?

Tags: php, html

Ну понятно, что php скрипты вставляют через `<?php ?>`. Но вот допустим у меня скрипт авторизации и страничка. Как сделать так, чтобы скрипт лежал в `cgi-bin`, а формочка лежала в `index.php` (главная страничка) или вообще с формой вместе в скрипте лежали

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зачем вам CGI если у вас есть РНР??

Не. Ну можно в первой строчке РНР-файла написать что-то вроде

```
#!/usr/bin/php
```

или

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php
```

Поставить на файл атрибуты +х (исполняемое), положить в cgi -папку и оно в массе своей серверов даже будет работать.

Но лучше использовать РНР как модуль, и просто ложить .php файл где-то в коде и указывать его в action формы.

Кстати. Если правило хорошего тона, не писать в формах ../../../, а писать путь от корня сервера /папка/скрипт.php

Answer (score 0):

что забред? с какой стати PHP вставляется в HTML? :) файлы .html не обрабатываются php обработчиком, если он должным образом не настроен... 
А вы знаете КАК работают формы? и что значит у `<form/>` аттрибут `action`? А как он работает? ;) очень рекомендую почитать, тогда все эти вопросы сразу уйдут.

Comment: если вы заметили я написал что главная страничка index.php .В таких случаях можно ставить)ну я же ставлю)и все работает)

Comment: я еще заметил заголовок :) в любом случае, у формы есть аттрибут action он и показывает куда отправлять введенные данные для обработки...

Comment: ладно..я наверно неправильно объяснил что мне надо.Я в html написал форму допустим для регистрации, и в action прописал ссылку на скрипт.он не ссылается хотя ссылка вроде верная.

Comment: <form method="post" action="../../cgi-bin/registration.php">
Имя: <br>
<input type="text" name="username" SIZE="20"  placeholder="Александр" required  /><br>
Фамилия:<br>
Логин: <br>
<input type="text" name="login" SIZE="20"placeholder="Koro" required /><br>
Пароль:<br>
<input type="password" name="password" SIZE="20" placeholder="Password" required /><br>
Повторите пароль: <br>
<input type="password" name="password_ch" SIZE="20" placeholder="Repeat password"  required /><br>
<input class="regbutton" type="submit" name="register" value="Register"/>
</form>

Comment: <?php
 $connect=mysql_connect('localhost','root') or die (mysql_error());
 mysql_select_db('noname');
 if(isset($_POST['register'])) 
  {
   $username=$_POST['username'];
   
   $login=$_POST['login'];
   $password=$_POST['password'];
   $password_ch=$_POST['password_ch'];
    if($password==$password_ch){
    $password=md5($password);
    $query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO trash VALUES ('','$username','$login','$password')") or die(mysql_error());
    }
    else
    {
    die('Passwords must be same');
    }
  }
?>

Comment: ммм, с точки зрения домена у вас где находится папка cgi-bin? т.е. если у вас папка доступна по адресу www.site.ru/cgi-bin/, то и надо так указывать /cgi-bin/registration.php   
ps; кстати, а почему пхп файл лежит там?? оно вообще обычно для cgi/perl используется....